# Host two ready websites with different URL using same code base

Tags: 7, uri, redirection, multi-sites

I’m pretty newbie to drupal and deploying stuffs. I’ve two separate drupal websites ready.

```
www.example.com
www.example.org
```

My directory structures on local machine for both websites are

```
wamp/www/example.com/sites/’all & default ‘ folder
wamp/www/example.org/sites/’all & default ‘ folder
```

These websites have complete different theme and database from each other. Now I want to go live for these two websites. But the problem is on hosting server they will provide me only 1 drupal installation.
 I need both URL’s working. (There is a setting for URL redirection on hosting).  But on hosting server, redirection via `.htaccess` is not running. (They said !!!).
 So my question is how to host two complete different websites on server with two complete different URLs using same drupal code base? I’m using drupal 7. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance…

Comment: You used domain names that belongs to commercial companies. In examples use http://example.com and http://example.org (with subdomains as needed) instead. Please edit your question. I'd prefer not to do that myself to avoid making it less useful for you.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for pointing that. I've no idea that these are commercial addresses. I've edited my question.

Comment: refere http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-multi-sites/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for [Multisite](https://drupal.org/node/43816) approach. It's pretty easy to set up and to keep sites separate, but if one day you'll need to share anything between sites, you'll regret not using Domain Access.

If you are sure there will be no need to share data, in `<drupal root>/sites` create 2 subdirectories, like `example.org` and `example.com`, and put site-specific files (modules, themes, libraries and settings.php) into them. Point both domains to your Drupal (your provider should be able to help with that) and Drupal will take care to recognize what site is accessed.

It might be worth to consider [Domain Access module](https://drupal.org/project/domain).

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database.